# Just updated to 12.10, now it's asking for a partial upgrade

Tags: 12.10, partial-upgrade, dist-upgrade

I just updated to 12.10 the other day, and after I successfully updated to 12.10, it's asking me to do a partial upgrade? I'm wary about it, because it shouldn't need a partial distribution upgrade, it already successfully upgraded, and it works great, and I'm worried if I let it run it'll break the install and I'll have to do a fresh install, and I really don't want to. Is it supposed to ask for a partial upgrade after successfully upgrading to 12.10?

I should also note that I upgraded from 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

- If you see 12.04 as the version, it means that the previous upgrade failed, and you should probably continue upgrading.
- However, if you see 12.10, you should not need to upgrade but I would recommend continuing as there might be some issue in the previous upgrade.

Comment: It says no lsb module, and that I'm in 12.10, so it successfully upgraded, I guess I should run the partial upgrade then? I'm just worried it might break the install...

Comment: I'd recommend continuing, but if it asks permission to download very large files which you think you already did as a part of your last upgrade, just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to run the partial upgrade, and I would have done it before but I forgot you can review what packages will be installed/removed/upgraded. Turns out the "partial dist upgrade" was actually just wanting to upgrade the Linux kernel, and Torchlight (a game I got from Humble Indie Bundle). Torchlight needed to be removed so the new version could be installed.